# How to access private function member through public function in C++?

Tags: c++, class, private-members

This program is used to do simple calculation of `area()` and `perimeter()` of a ***rectangle***. It's compiling and running fine but the answer is wrong(calculation). I think I messed up with private member functions by invoking them using public methods. Who could point out my mistake?

**recClass.h**

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

class Rectangle{
    public:
        Rectangle(double length = 1.0,double width = 1.0);
        void setLengthAndWidth(double,double);
        double getLength();
        double getWidth();
        void printAreaAndPerim();
    private:
        double length;
        double width;
        double perimeter();
        double area();
        
};

#endif
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

#include "recClass.h"

void Rectangle::setLengthAndWidth(double a,double b){
    length = a;
    width = b;
}
double Rectangle::getLength(){
    return length;
}
double Rectangle::getWidth(){
    return width;
}

double Rectangle::perimeter()
{
    double perim;
    perim = (length + width) * 2;
    return perim;
}

double Rectangle::area()
{
    double areaOfRec;
    areaOfRec = length * areaOfRec;
    return areaOfRec;
}

void Rectangle::printAreaAndPerim(){
    cout << "Has the Perimeter: " << perimeter() << "\nAnd area: " << area() << endl;
}
```

**//RectangleMain.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

#include "recClass.h"

int main()
{
    Rectangle rec;
    rec.setLengthAndWidth(4.2,5.5);
    
    cout << "Rectangle with length: " << rec.getLength() <<"\nand width: " << rec.getWidth() << endl;
    rec.printAreaAndPerim();
        
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The idea of private methods is to be used in other methods without it being accessible in the public API of your class.

Comment: `Rectangle::area()` uses an uninitialized variable, I suggest enabling compiler warnings to prevent this in the future.

Comment: @JVApen  yes I know,hence i put two functions for calculating are and perimeter in private. I just get wrong output, it gives me some junk

Comment: why use a variable at all for these simple functions just return the value directly, e.g: `double Rectangle::area() { return length * width; }`

Comment: @Stanley See my second comment

Comment: @JVApen do u know how to enable that in DEV IDE ? no info in the internet

Comment: I don't know what DEV IDE is, however, -Weverything or /W4 are a good way to start. After that, you have to disable the warnings that don't give added value (as compatibly with c++98)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 error in the code.

1. In the header file.
   The constructor name has a typo. 
   "Ractangle()".
2. In the area function of **Rechtangle.cpp**, the variable `areaOfRec` is uninitialised. And it is used in calculations. The function should be:

   area = length * width